# Inputting Terminal Commands When Running a Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

I just started using Rails a few days ago, and I'm having trouble with terminal commands. The textbook I am reading keeps telling me to run Terminal commands while having a Rails server running. This doesn't seem possible because the terminal just keeps outputting information about the server instead of prompting new commands, i.e. *rake test*. Is there a command I need to input to force the terminal to prompt my commands once I start the rails server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you will just start a second Terminal window or tab and run the commands your book mentions in there. It will use the same database, but not the same process your server is running in.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks so much!